# Error In Using Variable in Get-ADComputer Filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to import a list of computers from a CSV and check which are in our AD.  I am using the following code:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path $pathtoCSV
foreach ($c in $CSV) { 
  $PC = Get-ADComputer -Filter {dnshostname -eq $c.Name}
  # do more stuff with the results here
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Property: 'name' not found in object of type:
'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At line:1 char:30
+ foreach ($c in $csv) { $pc = Get-ADComputer -Filter {dnshostname -eq $c.name}
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Property: 'name' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

My CSV file looks like the following:

```
IP,Name,Mask,MAC,Expires,Type,
1.1.1.1,pcname.domain.com,255.255.255.0,ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff,10/27/2015 11:55:19 AM,DHCP
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15246639/1630171.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$CSV = Import-csv -path $pathtoCSV
foreach ($c in $CSV.Name) { 
  $PC = Get-ADComputer -filter {dnshostname -eq $c}
  # do more stuff with the results here
}
```

Or this

```
$CSV = Import-csv -path $pathtoCSV
foreach ($c in $CSV.Name) { 
  $PC = Get-ADComputer -Identity $c
  # do more stuff with the results here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Also, thanks Ansgar for the link to a similar question that explained why my code didn't work to begin with.